# untar single file error

Tags: tar

I am trying to untar a single file inside a big `tar.gz` file with this command:

```sh
tar -xvf files.tgz '/home/home_ndb_fp/DATI (ex parc.)/DOC AAA/AAAAA/TRES VIN/AAAA AAAA - AAAA AAA AAAA/BBBBBB by cccccc.net 14-01-2016/ORDER DDDDDDDD (Salvato automaticamente).xls'
```

but gave me an error

I also tried

```sh
tar -xvf files.tgz /home/home_ndb_fp/DATI\ \(ex\ parc.\)/DOC\ AAA/AAAAA/TRES\ VIN/AAAA\ AAAA\ \-\ AAAA\ AAA\ AAAA/BBBBBB\ by\ cccccc.net\ 14-01-2016/ORDER\ DDDDDDDD\ \(Salvato\ automaticamente).xls
```

but it did not work. I not try to untar all the archive because the file is very big 53GB .The error I give is in Italian:

```
non trovato nell'archivio (not find in the archive)
tar: Uscita per errore ritardata dall'errore precedente (exit from the error....
```

The gzipped tar is crated with symply backup. sbackupd and with other files works well. I think parenthesis make the problem. The name of the file including all path is inside `flist`, so the filename and path I'm sure is right.

Comment: can you please [edit] your question and include the error message you got? And what is the problem with "untaring" the whole archive and then getting the file?

Comment: Please rerun your command(s) with the prefix `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX` (e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX tar ...`) and [edit] your question to include the error message, that should now appear in English. What's the output of `tar -tzf files.tgz`? Does it contain the verbatim path, that you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "z" option to your tar command: tar -xzvf....

You can use "tar tvzf" to get a list of files in the archive and check that the file you want is named exactly as you expect. You can also use wildcards in the name of the file you want to extract, which might be easier than trying to get all the backslashes exactly correct.

Comment: i dont need to do tar -xzvf  because  symply backup do it when make the big tar.gzip, he make a textfile with inside the list of all compressed files, so i take the path and name of the file there... i've done the extraction of single file in the past with success.. i think the parenthesis make the problem..

Comment: the error in english is : Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Comment: In your command, you did not escape the last ')'

Comment: no, i escaped all () .. it's a mistake i change the names of the files beacause they contain sensitive data and i forgot to escape it only in the post

Comment: last infos... i've phisicall access to qnap where the backup was stored today.. i take the 53 gb file. and did some test. for unknown reason the file has problems, only this one, i try with many others bakups and they works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to put the name of the file that you want to extract in another file, say files.txt, without any escape characters. Then use tar xvTf files.txt files.tgz.

Comment: Please don't add a second answer to a question. Instead you should edit your first answer and include the alternative solution

Comment: No, this is a completely different answer!!!